# Laravel 9 Attempt to assign property "category_id" on null

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I can't understand why it doesn't work, if the number is lower than 100000 everything works perfectly if I try to open this 684356 existing database it gives me this error, all higher numbers give me this error, lower numbers it works perfectly, from what does it depend?

An example if I open a category with number 31085 --> this works
An example if I open a category with number 684356 --> Attempt to assign property "category_id" on null

Controller

```
    public function editAttributes(Request $request, $category_id){
        Session::put('page','tickets-log');
        $category_logs = TicketsLog::find($request->category_id);
        $category_logs->category_id= $request->category_id;
        $category_logs->category_name = $request->category_name;
        $category_logs->category_desc = $request->category_desc;
        $category_logs->category_not = $request->category_not ;
        $category_logs->category_not2 = $request->category_not2;
        $category_logs->category_not3 = $request->category_not3;
        $category_logs->category_not4 = $request->category_not4;
        if($category_logs->save()){
            return view('attributes.edit', compact('category_logs'));
        }
    }
```

Blade

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('edit-attributes')}}/{{ $category_logs->category_id }}" method="post">@csrf
                                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <h5 class="card-title">Category :</h5>
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="category_id" value="{{ $category_logs['category_id']}}" readonly="">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: open TicketsLog  $fillable = ['category_id',....]; add

Comment: Are you sure you have row in TicketsLog table with that id?

Comment: yes 100% sure, if I open to see I see everything, if I enter to modify I get that error, and only on higher numbers, low ones work perfectly

Comment: try changing to $category_logs = TicketsLog::findOrFail($request->category_id); and does it returns a 404 error?

Comment: yes it gives me the 404 page if I insert this $category_logs = TicketsLog::findOrFail($request->category_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the action attribute. Instead of

```
action="{{url('edit-attributes')}}/{{ $category_logs->category_id }}" put action="{{ url('edit-attributes',$category_logs->category_id ) }}".
```

I don't know how you defined the route.

If you have the `{category_id}` attribute defined in the route, change

```
TicketsLog::find($request->category_id); 
in 
TicketsLog::find($category_id);
```

or
If category_id isn't defined as primary key this table

```
 TicketsLog::where('category_id','=',$category_id)->first();
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, it keeps giving the exact same error  app
 / 
Http
 / 
Controllers
 / 
TicketsController
.php
 
: 404 Attempt to assign property "category_id" on null

Comment: Route::match(['get','post'],'edit-attributes/{category_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\TicketsController::class, 'editAttributes']); <--- this is my route

Comment: I inserted in the model protected $fillable = ['category_id'];,
I changed this <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url('edit-attributes/'.$category_logs['category_id']) }}">@csrf
I modified in the controller $category_logs = TicketsLog::find($category_id);,
but it keeps giving me error after a certain number, exceeded 10000 by error, under this number it works, this thing is absurd

Comment: no its not the primary key, i need to find that to get the results of all the rows that are linked to that number, TicketsLog::where('category_id','=',$category_id)->first(); <--->SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '684356' in 'where clause'

Comment: I inserted what you suggested into the controller and now it works, thanks for the help, now it doesn't give any more errors ---> TicketsLog::where('category_id','=',$category_id)->first(); ---->the solution was this, thanks for the support